# How do you select an image from an array of images and send that image to another screen -React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and need help finding a way to select an image from an array of images on one screen and send the user selected image to another screen

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's difficult to help you but i will give you some ideas...

- use Redux to manage your state and access from every component
- send your uri with props
- use react-navigation and send the uri as a param